# Why is apache rendering internal ip?

Tags: routing, apache-httpd

I have apache running on 192.168.0.2 (localhost), and a NAS on 192.168.0.32. When I set apache to listen to port 80, attempts to connect to my external ip produce a connection refused error, while connection from localhost succeed. When the apache service is stopped, connections both internal and external produce a connection refused error. However when I set apache to listen to port 8080, visiting localhost:8080 works, but visits to port 80 from localhost get the default "It works!" page, while requests to my external ip instead get the web interface for the NAS - which as I said, is at 192.168.0.32!

This is on Ubuntu 15.10. No iptables or other software firewall has been set up. The router has been configured to explicitly disallow any external requests, although that is apparently not working.

To summarize:

1.

- When Apache, on 192.168.0.2, is set to listen to port 8080 ONLY
- requests to 192.168.0.2:8080 work correctly
- requests to 192.168.0.2:80 are displaying my index (should be refused)
- external requests display the web interface on 192.168.0.32

2.

- When Apache, on 192.168.0.2, is set to listen to port 80 ONLY
- requests to 192.168.0.2:80 work correctly
- requests to 192.168.0.2:8080 refuse connection (correctly)
- external requests get a connection refused error

What is going on!?